# How to add tag/attributes to XCUITest(Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, automated-tests, xcuitest

I am trying to figure out if we have any way to set Tag/Attribute to tests in Swift. 
In C# we use to tag test based on feature and test type that use to help us in reporting.
Below is the example :-

[Category("LongRunning"),Category("Workspace")]
  public class LongRunningTests {
  ...
  }

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are no built-in options to no annotate test cases and test classes in Swift.

You shall add Dictionary containing tests names and their groups in your custom XCTestCase and override invokeTest() based on this Dictionary.

Your annotations may look something like this:

```
class TestClass: CustomUITestCase {

    override var testClassesGrouping: [TestClassesGroups] { return  [.positiveScenarios] }
    override var testCasesGrouping: [String: [TestCasesGroups]] { return
        ["testReminderWithNotes": [.testSettingNotes],
         "testPastReminder": [.testChangingDate],
         "testFutureReminder": [.testChangingDate],
         "testFuturePrioritised": [.testChangingDate, .testSettingPriority],
         "testPrioritisedReminder": [.testSettingPriority]]
    }
    ... 
}
```